# Properties of $a \ast b =|a \cdot b|$ where $|x|$ is the module of complex number on the set $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's define on set $\mathbb{C}$ operation $\ast$ with equality
$$ a \ast b =|a \cdot b| $$
where $|x|$ marks module of the complex number.

Is the operation an algebraic operation? Is it associative, commutative, is there a unity element, what kind of elements are reversible? What kind of algebraic structure is this?

So I tried to advance further without the lessons and ran into this problem. Does it work the same way as other sets like $\mathbb{R}$  or does it have some kind of extra things I am not aware of? How to do the operations with module of the complex number? Any help is greatly appreciated and I am sorry in advance because I am pretty sure some of my questions are a bit foolish.

Comment: Did you try to check any of the properties yourself? Also, what do you mean by "is it an algebraic operation"? What is the definition of algebraic operation?

Comment: I tried but I am not sure how the module of the complex numbers behaves. Works it the same way as any normal multiplication in that sense or has some different properties like usually the complex numbers have.

Comment: + for example: An algebraic operation on set A is a mapping from set $A \times A \rightarrow A $. So I would say it's algebraic :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commutative, since complex multiplication is so, and also associative, based on $|a\cdot b|=|a|\cdot|b|$.
So, it's a *commutative semigroup*.

It doesn't have a unit element because it only can produce positive real numbers, so for no element $e$ will we have $e*i=i$ (neither $e*(-1)=-1$).

Therefore we can't talk about neither invertible elements.